# Trying to to use GridLayouther (the dialog is greyed and frozen)

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I'm trying to use a grid layout, but the window is all grey and you can not move the window around.

The demo code I used to get started had a grid layout of 3,3 with a JButton in each box, and it worked fine.

When I change the JBUttons to JLabel, it no-loner worked. It drew the 3 by 3 grid but the dialog box stayed grey and was frozen.

My code that does not work.

```
public class cEditIndicators extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    JFrame f;  

    public cEditIndicators() {  

        f=new JFrame();  

        JLabel b1=new JLabel("1");             
        JLabel b2=new JLabel("2");  
        JLabel b3=new JLabel("3");  
        JLabel b4=new JLabel("4");  
        JLabel b5=new JLabel("5");  
        JLabel b6=new JLabel("6");  
        JLabel b7=new JLabel("7");  
        JLabel b8=new JLabel("8");  
        JLabel b9=new JLabel("9");  

        f.add(b1);f.add(b2);f.add(b3);f.add(b4);f.add(b5);  
        f.add(b6);f.add(b7);f.add(b8);f.add(b9);  

        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));  
        //setting grid layout of 3 rows and 3 columns  

        f.setSize(300,300);  
        f.setVisible(true);     
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: You're not new and should know the drill -- please post actual [mcve] code that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: You change the layout after added components to the previous layout.

Comment: Ok read Minimal and Complete exmple,

Comment: your code is working fine or do you expect to be able to click the `JLabel`s? yet you should extend JFrame or use JDialog all along and not just extend it without calling `super()`